# Excel Consolidate data - Average if?

Tags: excel, average

Is it possible to consolidate data using the Consolidate function in excel (MI Professional Plus 2016) using an AverageIf 0?

I can only see Average as an option but my data had 0 and I don't want those scores to be included in the average.

Any suggestions welcomed?

I know Averageif is a function in general but I don't see it working with Consolidate.

Thanks

Comment: Why not try using `POWER QUERY`?

Comment: have you considered something like averageif(range,">0") ?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, he is asking that whether he can use the `AVERAGEIF` Function in `CONSOLIDATE` functionality present in `DATA` Tab under `Data Tools` group, may be i am wrong, but i assume he might be asking for the same, could you correct me sir

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya well, without a decent example who can be sure. But would consolidate be needed just to avoid counting 0 ?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, not really, in that case, `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS` works better, but as OP mentioned he needs to consolidate so i assumed, I agree with your point that a minimum reproducible example is always needs to be shown with before and after output, so that becomes easier for someone to understand and provide a solution at least a MOCK data set

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya if, as you agree averageif() works better, what are you going on about?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, OP is asking that whether he can use that functionality in the Consolidate which is not present, so i suggested to use `POWER QUERY`

Comment: I have multiple sheets so I would like to use the consolidate function under the data tab. But the options for function only include Average not Avergaeif. So my question is, is there a way to consolidate using avergaeif? Also I am not a very experienced excel user.  Thank you

Comment: I have said earlier try using `POWER QUERY` it will be better here, use GroupBy functionality in PQ to do the `AVERAGE IF`